# Backticks don't work with strikethrough in chat

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

If you do a `**bold**` with backticks around it, it shows the stars, but if you don't use them, you'll just get **bold**. And it's the same with most other styling punctuation marks.

However it does not work with `---strike---` in chat, and instead of getting it like it does here, I get this:

[image: Strike not working as it should in ``]

Though I wrote it with the backticks. And it gets stranger, if I edit the message it will sometimes become `---Strike---` rather than ---Strike---, and then work for most of the time (after it has stopped being green, before then it does the line through even if it's not meant to) until some seemingly random time when it stops working again.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheTux: Oh, thanks for fixing my styling mess! I didn't realise I did that! :D

Comment: What browser? What userscripts/addons/extensions you have? What if you try with a different browser?

Answer (score 4):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) on my side:

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

(Google Chrome 47.0.2526.80 64-bit / Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 64-bit)

When you send `---Strike---` the message is temporarily shown as <del>Strike</del> before updating and becoming `---Strike---`; I suspect auchatstatus or some other userscript / Javascript related thing on your client interfering with this update.

Comment: Confirmed the temporary misparsing. Looks like there is *some* kind of a bug here, if only in the fact that the client-side chat message preview is disagreeing with the server-side Markdown parser.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I just tested in the Sandbox and it looks like backticks-processing is done server-side. \`*Italic*\` and \`**Bold**\` are formatted in the preview as well, in the same way whatever is put in between backticks is *not* formatted as inline code. So apparently the problem is that OP's client is not rendering the server-side-processed formatting.